# prove $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0$ using epsilon delta

Tags: limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

prove using Epsilon Delta that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0$, where
$f(x) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \;\;\; \sqrt6 \;x & \quad \text{if } {x \in \mathbb{Q}}\\
    -\sqrt6 \;x & \quad \text{if } {x \not\in \mathbb{Q}}
  \end{array} \right.$

I know that in order to prove it, I must use: $$\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt6}$$

Would the proper proof method be that I must show that the $\delta$ value is the same regardless of if $x$ is rational or irrational?

i.E. Do I show the following?

When $x \in \mathbb{Q}:$
$$0 < \; \mid x \mid \; < \delta \implies \mid \sqrt6 \;x \mid \; < \sqrt6 \; \delta = \epsilon$$

When $x \not\in \mathbb{Q}:$
$$0 < \; \mid x \mid \; < \delta \implies \mid -\sqrt6 \;x \mid \; < \sqrt6 \; \delta = \epsilon$$

Of course, I am not saying the above is the complete proof, but is that the correct strategy in proving it? I haven't done epsilon-delta proofs on a piece-wise function before, which is why I am asking.

Comment: $|-\sqrt6 x|=|\sqrt6 x| = \sqrt6 |x| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x| < \delta$

Comment: You don't need to spend time showing that $\delta$ is the same regardless of if $x$ is rational or not, because $\delta$ should be independent of $x$. Instead use the fact that $|-a|=|a|$ for $a \in \Bbb{R}$

Comment: Prove the squeeze theorem, and show this function applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, regardless of whether $x\in\Bbb Q$ or not, $|f(x)|=|\pm x\sqrt6|=|x|\sqrt6$.